# chrome extension not working on javascript contentScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have been working on a chrome extension and earlier i made some changes to the chrome extension , i added in a couple feautres on the contentScript and ever since then , it has hasnt been working ive been either getting unexpected token errors or just general syntax issues , i am not the best when it comes to javascript / jquery and i cant figure out where the issue lies , i beleive it is somewhere near the bottom to do with the indentation of the code between the firebase and the script , if anyone has any ideas why and where i am going wrong and can point me in the right direction i would greatly appricitate it , i do not get any errors in the console just doesnt execute the script and doesnt work

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    let playerDataMap = new Map();
    function loadPlayerDataFromCsv() {
        console.log('**LOADING PLAYER DATA**');
        $.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TheWraith1912/Project1/main/iconsxb.csv", function(CSVdata) {
            var lines = CSVdata.split("\n");
            var headers = lines[0].split(",");

            for (var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
                if (lines[i] != "") {
                    var currentline = lines[i].replaceAll('"', "").split(",");
                    var name = currentline[0].normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").split(" ");
                    let key = name[name.length - 1] + currentline[1];
                    let value = currentline[2].trim();
                    playerDataMap.set(key, value);
                }
            }
        });
        console.log('**LOADED PLAYER DATA**');
    }

    function addStyleElement() {
        if ($('style[title="highlightStyle"]').length > 0) {
            return;
        }
        var t = document.createElement("style");
        t.type = "text/css",
        t.innerText = "\n    .SearchResults.ui-layout-left .listFUTItem {\n        height: 39px;\n    }\n    .SearchResults.ui-layout-left .listFUTItem .label {\n        font-size: 10px;\n  }\n    .SearchResults.ui-layout-left .auction {\n        margin-top: 0 !important;\n        font-size: 12px;\n        top: 4px;\n    }\n",
        document.head.appendChild(t);
    }

    function waitForSearchButton() {
        console.log('**WAITING FOR TRANSFER SEARCH BUTTON**');
        let searchButtonCandidate = $('.btn-standard.call-to-action');
        if (searchButtonCandidate.length > 0 && searchButtonCandidate[0] && $(searchButtonCandidate[0]).text() === 'Search') {
            console.log('**SEARCH BUTTON FOUND**');
            $('.btn-standard.call-to-action').on("keyup", function(event) {
                if (event.key == "b")
                    addStyleElement();
                highlightValues();
            });

            console.log('**SEARCH BUTTON READY TO CLICK**');
        } else {
            setTimeout(function() {
                waitForSearchButton();
            }, 2000);
        }
    }

    function highlightValues() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('Getting Everything Ready');
            getPlayerDataFromSite();
            //$('.pagination.prev').on('click', function(e){
            $('.pagination.prev').keyup(function(e) {
                if (e.keycode == 37)
                    e.preventDefault();
                addStyleElement();
                console.log('**PREVIOUS**');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    getPlayerDataFromSite();
                }, 500);
            });

            //$('.pagination.next').on('click', function(e){
            $('.pagination.next').keyup(function(e) {
                if (e.keycode == 39)
                    e.preventDefault();
                addStyleElement();
                console.log('**NEXT**');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    getPlayerDataFromSite();
                }, 500);
            });
        }, 1000);
    }

    function getPlayerDataFromSite() {
        for (var i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
            var name = $('.name:eq(' + i + ')').text();
            name = name.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
            var rating = $('.rating:eq(' + i + ')').text();
            var fullName = name.split(' ');
            var sitePlayerPrice = '';
            if ($('.auction:eq(' + i + ')').children('div').eq(2).text().split(":")[1] != undefined) {
                sitePlayerPrice = $('.auction:eq(' + i + ')').children('div').eq(2).text().split(":")[1].replaceAll(",", "");
            }
            var excelDataSheetPrice = playerDataMap.get(fullName[fullName.length - 1] + "" + rating);
            console.log('ExcelSheetPrice', fullName[fullName.length - 1] + "" + rating, "==>", excelDataSheetPrice);
            console.log('SitePrice', name + "" + rating + "==>", sitePlayerPrice);

            let sitePlayerPriceAsNumber = parseInt(sitePlayerPrice);
            if (!excelDataSheetPrice || !sitePlayerPriceAsNumber) {
                continue;
            }

            if (sitePlayerPriceAsNumber <= parseInt(excelDataSheetPrice * 1.03)) {
                console.log('**' + fullName + ' IS Orange NOW**')
                $('.name:eq(' + i + ')').parent().css('background-color', 'orange');
            }
            if (sitePlayerPriceAsNumber <= parseInt(excelDataSheetPrice * 1.01)) {
                console.log('**' + fullName + ' IS GREY NOW**')
                $('.name:eq(' + i + ')').parent().css('background-color', 'grey');
            }
            if (sitePlayerPriceAsNumber <= parseInt(excelDataSheetPrice)) {
                console.log('**' + fullName + ' IS GREEN NOW**')
                $('.name:eq(' + i + ')').parent().css('background-color', 'green');
            }
            if (sitePlayerPriceAsNumber <= parseInt(excelDataSheetPrice * 0.97)) {
                console.log('**' + fullName + ' IS Magenta NOW**')
                $('.name:eq(' + i + ')').parent().css('background-color', 'magenta');
            }
            if (sitePlayerPriceAsNumber <= parseInt(excelDataSheetPrice * 0.80)) {
                console.log('**' + fullName + ' IS RED NOW**')
                $('.name:eq(' + i + ')').parent().css('background-color', 'red');
            }
        }

    }

    loadPlayerDataFromCsv();
    waitForSearchButton();

    chrome.storage.local.get(["loggedIn"], function(result) {
        if (result.loggedIn === true) {
            func();
        } else {

            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                cmd: "showNotification"
            }, function(response) {});

        }
    })
}
)
```

Comment: `console.log('**LOADED PLAYER DATA**');` will execute long before your data is loaded, since `$.get` is asynchronous

Comment: sorry what does this mean

Comment: Well you are calling some service with `$.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com..)`. This will take some time, even if it's like 1 second. In the meantime, Javascript doesn't stop running (it's non-blocking). So it runs the next line : `console.log('**LOADED PLAYER DATA**')` So that is done. Then there's no more code to run because it's the end of the function. Then, one second later, the web service you called responds with data. At that moment, the callback function gets triggered and `var lines = CSVdata.split` gets executed. One second _after_ you got the `'**LOADED PLAYER DATA**'` log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare an anonymous function `(function(){...})` but that's it, you don't run it. Add `()` at the end to execute your function : `(function(){...})()`

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    let playerDataMap = new Map();
    function loadPlayerDataFromCsv() {
        console.log('**LOADING PLAYER DATA**');
        $.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TheWraith1912/Project1/main/iconsxb.csv", function (CSVdata) {
            var lines = CSVdata.split("\n");
            var headers = lines[0].split(",");

            for (var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
                if (lines[i] != "") {
                    var currentline = lines[i].replaceAll('"', "").split(",");
                    var name = currentline[0].normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").split(" ");
                    let key = name[name.length - 1] + currentline[1];
                    let value = currentline[2].trim();
                    playerDataMap.set(key, value);
                }
            }
        });
        console.log('**LOADED PLAYER DATA**');
    }

    function addStyleElement() {
        if ($('style[title="highlightStyle"]').length > 0) {
            return;
        }
        var t = document.createElement("style");
        t.type = "text/css",
            t.innerText = "\n    .SearchResults.ui-layout-left .listFUTItem {\n        height: 39px;\n    }\n    .SearchResults.ui-layout-left .listFUTItem .label {\n        font-size: 10px;\n  }\n    .SearchResults.ui-layout-left .auction {\n        margin-top: 0 !important;\n        font-size: 12px;\n        top: 4px;\n    }\n",
            document.head.appendChild(t);
    }

    function waitForSearchButton() {
        console.log('**WAITING FOR TRANSFER SEARCH BUTTON**');
        let searchButtonCandidate = $('.btn-standard.call-to-action');
        if (searchButtonCandidate.length > 0 && searchButtonCandidate[0] && $(searchButtonCandidate[0]).text() === 'Search') {
            console.log('**SEARCH BUTTON FOUND**');
            $('.btn-standard.call-to-action').on("keyup", function (event) {
                if (event.key == "b")
                    addStyleElement();
                highlightValues();
            });

            console.log('**SEARCH BUTTON READY TO CLICK**');
        } else {
            setTimeout(function () {
                waitForSearchButton();
            }, 2000);
        }
    }

    function highlightValues() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('Getting Everything Ready');
            getPlayerDataFromSite();
            //$('.pagination.prev').on('click', function(e){
            $('.pagination.prev').keyup(function (e) {
                if (e.keycode == 37)
                    e.preventDefault();
                addStyleElement();
                console.log('**PREVIOUS**');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    getPlayerDataFromSite();
                }, 500);
            });

            //$('.pagination.next').on('click', function(e){
            $('.pagination.next').keyup(function (e) {
                if (e.keycode == 39)
                    e.preventDefault();
                addStyleElement();
                console.log('**NEXT**');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    getPlayerDataFromSite();
                }, 500);
            });
        }, 1000);
    }

    function getPlayerDataFromSite() {
        for (var i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
            var name = $('.name:eq(' + i + ')').text();
            name = name.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
            var rating = $('.rating:eq(' + i + ')').text();
            var fullName = name.split(' ');
            var sitePlayerPrice = '';
            if ($('.auction:eq(' + i + ')').children('div').eq(2).text().split(":")[1] != undefined) {
                sitePlayerPrice = $('.auction:eq(' + i + ')').children('div').eq(2).text().split(":")[1].replaceAll(",", "");
            }
            var excelDataSheetPrice = playerDataMap.get(fullName[fullName.length - 1] + "" + rating);
            console.log('ExcelSheetPrice', fullName[fullName.length - 1] + "" + rating, "==>", excelDataSheetPrice);
            console.log('SitePrice', name + "" + rating + "==>", sitePlayerPrice);

            let sitePlayerPriceAsNumber = parseInt(sitePlayerPrice);
            if (!excelDataSheetPrice || !sitePlayerPriceAsNumber) {
                continue;
            }

            if (sitePlayerPriceAsNumber <= parseInt(excelDataSheetPrice * 1.03)) {
                console.log('**' + fullName + ' IS Orange NOW**')
                $('.name:eq(' + i + ')').parent().css('background-color', 'orange');
            }
            if (sitePlayerPriceAsNumber <= parseInt(excelDataSheetPrice * 1.01)) {
                console.log('**' + fullName + ' IS GREY NOW**')
                $('.name:eq(' + i + ')').parent().css('background-color', 'grey');
            }
            if (sitePlayerPriceAsNumber <= parseInt(excelDataSheetPrice)) {
                console.log('**' + fullName + ' IS GREEN NOW**')
                $('.name:eq(' + i + ')').parent().css('background-color', 'green');
            }
            if (sitePlayerPriceAsNumber <= parseInt(excelDataSheetPrice * 0.97)) {
                console.log('**' + fullName + ' IS Magenta NOW**')
                $('.name:eq(' + i + ')').parent().css('background-color', 'magenta');
            }
            if (sitePlayerPriceAsNumber <= parseInt(excelDataSheetPrice * 0.80)) {
                console.log('**' + fullName + ' IS RED NOW**')
                $('.name:eq(' + i + ')').parent().css('background-color', 'red');
            }
        }

    }

    loadPlayerDataFromCsv();
    waitForSearchButton();

    chrome.storage.local.get(["loggedIn"], function (result) {
        if (result.loggedIn === true) {
            func();
        } else {

            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                cmd: "showNotification"
            }, function (response) { });

        }
    })
})() // <--- this
```

Comment: thank you , in which line do i add "()" to?

Comment: Well, at the very end. You define a giant encapsulating function, but you don't run it. So nothing runs at all. How could you write so much code without ever being able to run it??

Comment: sorry if im being slow , i just didnt write this myself and they dont know where the error was either im not sure where to add the () into becuse i just get unexpected ")"

Comment: Full code recopied in my answer, with the `()` at the end

Comment: No worries! Code runs better when you execute it ;)